# How do I keep my Chrome bookmarks on my 2 different mac's in sync?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Is it possible to keep my Chrome bookmarks synced on both my mac's?  i.e. I want to add a bookmark at work and then have it at home.

I believe Safari does this with iCloud, but I don't like using Safari.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Options > Personal Stuff:

> chrome://settings/personal

Sign in with your Google account and then click on **Advanced...** then make sure that the "Bookmarks" option is ticked:

[image: Advanced sync preferences]